# How I Can Add Link In Header For Social Media Icon?

Tags: link, social

I am trying to find the option that how I can edit the link of google plus in header.

I find in `CMS > Static block` but no success, Please help me, How can I edit or add the link

[image]

Comment: are you using custom theme ? if so, which one ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

I was using my custom theme.  Go to folder `app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <container name="custom.header" htmlClass="headerSitemenu" htmlTag="div">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="social.links" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::social-links.phtml">
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
```

My custom .phtml file name is social-links.phtml.  In this file I have the following code.  This file is located at `<mage-root>/app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Theme/templates/social-links.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// Social Icons Bar
// custom file added by Cameron Dixon

?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('header_social_test')->toHtml();?>
```

So my custom CMS Block name is

> "header_social_test"